# Proof that different representations of gamma matrices are connected by a unitary transformation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-matrices, unitarity

The different representations of gamma matrices are related by a similarity transformation
\begin{equation}
\gamma^{\mu'}=S\gamma^{\mu}S^{-1}
\end{equation}
for some non-singular $S$. I have to prove that $S$ is actually unitary. To do so, I first consider the case $\mu=0$. We then have
\begin{equation}
\gamma^{0'}=S\gamma^{0}S^{-1}
\end{equation}
Now $(\gamma^{0'})^{\dagger}=\gamma^{0'}$. Using this I have
\begin{equation}
S^{-1}(S^{-1})^{\dagger}\gamma^{0}S^{\dagger}S=S^{-1}S\gamma^{0}S^{-1}S=\gamma^{0}=I\gamma^{0}I
\end{equation}
So that I can write $S^{\dagger}S=aI, a\in \mathbb{R}$. Similarly using $(\gamma^{0})^{\dagger}=\gamma^{0}$,
\begin{equation}
SS^{\dagger}\gamma^{0'}(S^{-1})^{\dagger}S=SS^{-1}\gamma^{0'}SS^{-1}=\gamma^{0'}=I\gamma^{0'}I
\end{equation}
So that I can write $SS^{\dagger}=bI, b\in \mathbb{R}$. Now
\begin{equation}
det\left(SS^{\dagger}\right)=b^4=det\left(S^{\dagger}S\right)=a^4=>a=b
\end{equation}
Then we end up with
\begin{equation}
SS^{\dagger}=S^{\dagger}S=aI
\end{equation}
So S is not unitary unless $a=1$.

If we use the normalization condition $det\left(S\right)=det\left(S^{\dagger}\right)=1$, $a$ equals $1$ and $S$ becomes unitary. However, the choice of normalisation seems arbitrary to me. Is there any other way by which I can show that $S$ is truely unitary?

Comment: Of course not. For any $S$ that works, $aS$ will also work.

Comment: I don't understand your proof, how do you conclude that $S^\dagger S=aI$? This doesn't seem to follow from the previous equation...